# Node.js client for a socket.io server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io server running and a matching webpage with a socket.io.js client. All works fine.

But, I am wondering if it is possible, on another machine, to run a separate node.js application which would act as a client and connect to the mentioned socket.io server?

Comment: How do I view the response from socket.emit()?

Comment: Go through the https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client documentation, I am sure it is there. It has been a while, so I do not remember, sorry...

Comment: It isn't working if `io.connect` function is called as you mentioned. It should be called as: `socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

That should be possible using Socket.IO-client: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Comment: Uhm, I might be mistaking, but this looks like the client that runs within the browser. What I need is a stand-alone node.js client.

Comment: I haven't checked recently, but in Node 0.4.x this worked on the server too (I have actually implemented this in a past project).

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Btw, it's better to put your working example on the question rather than in a separate answer.

Comment: This didn't install correctly for me on windows 8 - i wrote a bug for it

Comment: @PredragStojadinović : Can you please post your code? I want to connect  one NodeJS sever to another. Can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108594/node-js-socket-io-client-is-not-connecting-to-socket-io-server

Answer (score 62):

Adding in example for solution given earlier. By using `socket.io-client` https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Client Side:

```
//client.js
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
socket.emit('CH01', 'me', 'test msg');
```

Server Side :

```
//server.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function (socket){
   console.log('connection');

  socket.on('CH01', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('MSG', from, ' saying ', msg);
  });

});

http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Run :

Open 2 console and run `node server.js` and `node client.js`

Comment: Awesome examples!  One thing, on the client side, I don't believe the "socket" variable gets passed on the connection event.  Maybe I'm wrong, but that seems to be the behavior I'm seeing with npm socket.io-client

Comment: Did you fix that yet @RyanS

Comment: @Bombosonic yo!  shoot, this was a while ago lol, I don't remember what I ended up doing, sorry!

Answer (score 14):

After installing socket.io-client:

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

This is how the client code looks like:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {
    port: 1337,
    reconnect: true
});
socket.on('connect', function () { console.log("socket connected"); });
socket.emit('private message', { user: 'me', msg: 'whazzzup?' });
```

Thanks [alessioalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617839/alessioalex).

Comment: can you emit without waiting for a socket connection? my emissions fail and when I look at the `socket.connected` property right before the `.emit()` it's `false`

Answer (score 2):

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket_url = "http://localhost:8081";

let socket = io.connect(socket_url);

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit("event_name", {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any client as long as it is supported by socket.io. No matter whether its node, java, android or swift. All you have to do is install the client package of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Client side code: I had a requirement where my nodejs webserver should work as both server as well as client, so i added below code when i need it as client, It should work fine, i am using it and working fine for me!!!

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.0.8:5000', {
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 10000
          });
    
        socket.on('connect', (data) => {
            console.log('Connected to Socket');
        });
        
        socket.on('event_name', (data) => {
            console.log("-----------------received event data from the socket io server");
        });
    
        //either 'io server disconnect' or 'io client disconnect'
        socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
            console.log("client disconnected");
            if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
              // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
              console.log("server disconnected the client, trying to reconnect");
              socket.connect();
            }else{
                console.log("trying to reconnect again with server");
            }
            // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
          });
    
        socket.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this worked for me

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ccStreamer = new WebSocket('wss://somthing.com');

ccStreamer.on('open', function open() {
  var subRequest = {
    "action": "SubAdd",
    "subs": [""]
  };
  ccStreamer.send(JSON.stringify(subRequest));
});

ccStreamer.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```