# server-side connection to a socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Java server that connects with web-browsers through web-sockets, specifically socket.io, specifically this implementation: https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio

Now I would like to connect to the same server, not from a web-browser (through Javascript), but from a Node.JS program.

The problem is, in all examples that I found, the Node.JS program is the server, and the clients are always web-browsers.

I tried to use a code similar to the client connection code in node.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:9080");
```

but got this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'
```

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703513/node-js-client-for-a-socket-io-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use socketio-client

```
$ npm install socket.io-client
```

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

You can then connect to another socket server by the following:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  // socket connected
});
```