# Node.js app fails to connect using socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

### Background

I have a Node.js server using `socket.io` that accepts connections from clients via HTTPS.

I know this server works as I am able to connect to it via browser.

### Problem

The problem is that I can't create a node app to connect to this server as a client.

I am using the following code:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io.connect("https://my.website.com:3002", { secure: true, reconnect: true });

socket.on("connect", function(){
    console.log("connected");
});

socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("disconnected");
});

socket.on("error", console.error);
```

The server registers no connections, and this app logs no errors. It would seem that I am connecting to the wrong server, but this same URL works just fine when I use a browser.

### Research

I have searched github and the official docs for an answer. Even similar questions from stackoverflow seem to not work:

- [Node.js client for a socket.io server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703513/node-js-client-for-a-socket-io-server)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client
- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/828

### Question

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I have the exact same code on browser and it works. This is what I find hard to understand.

Comment: btw running your code results in no output for me too :D

Comment: I got an output adding: `socket.on("connect_error", function(e){
 console.log("connect_error", e);
});` and waiting 20 sec. Looks like the `error` event is not emited for all types of errors -.-

Comment: @RolandStarke That information is quite precious. Thanks !

Comment: I think it might be important to mention specifically the use of `https` in the title, as I spent 2 days hunting for this solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Answer

After realising, that not all errors feed into the `"error"` event ( special thanks to @RolandStarke ) I found that I was having a consistent XHR pool request:

```
{ Error: xhr poll error
    at XHR.Transport.onError (/Users/pedro/Workspace/backend-stresser/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:64:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pedro/Workspace/backend-stresser/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:128:10)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (/Users/pedro/Workspace/backend-stresser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Request.onError (/Users/pedro/Workspace/backend-stresser/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:310:8)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/pedro/Workspace/backend-stresser/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:257:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5) type: 'TransportError', description: 503 }
```

Once I had this information, I made a quick search and found a solution to this issue, which seems to be a bug:

- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1097

The code I am now using is:

```
const socket = io.connect("https://my.website.com:3002", { secure: true, reconnection: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: After 2 days of bashing my head against a wall, this answer saved my arse. NONE of the other examples/answers that I found show how to do it with `https`

Comment: Good to know I helped :P

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I am getting Parse Error HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT any clue?

Comment: For me the key is `rejectUnauthorized: false` because I'm using a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this code in my client side and it worked:

```
import io from "socket.io-client"
const SERVER = "http://localhost:5000"
const socket = io(SERVER, { transports: ["websocket"] })
```

Comment: Adding transports parameters in socket constructor helped me a lot! Thanks!