# Connecting Node.js and Python with socket.io

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, socket.io

## Brief

I am trying to connect Node.js[client] and Python [server]. Python server only supports WebSocket where Node.js socket.io is trying with long polling setting transport: [websocket].after all setup I am getting no data and node.js socket.io is trying to re-connect to server all the time.

## Requirement

Python and Node.js connected with each other by websocket.where Node.js is a client and Python is server side.

## Code

1. Python

   ```
   # IMPORT'S
   import asyncio # core: python async-await library.
   import string # core: python string manipulatation library.
   import json # core: json library.
   import pydash # pip: utility module.
   from starlette.applications import Starlette # pip: http framework.
   from starlette.responses import JSONResponse # pip: http response handler.
   from starlette.websockets import WebSocket # pip: websocket library.
   import uvicorn # pip: server runner.

   # SYSTEM IMPORT'S
   from system import Connect # system: load engine connection.
   from www.template import Template # system: route template loader

   # ENGINE: STARLETTE
   App = Starlette()
   App.debug = True

   # GLOBAL'S
   _port = 8000
   _host = '0.0.0.0'

   # HANDLER: APP
   """
   Details: Allow's external connection to interact
   with system core.rightnow socket connection can
   be made.
   """
   class App:
      def __init__(self, scope):
          assert scope['type'] == 'websocket'
          self.scope = scope

      async def __call__(self, receive, send):
         # load and accept socket.io connection.
         _WebSocket = WebSocket(self.scope, receive=receive, send=send)
         await _WebSocket.accept()

         # local variable's.
         _templateName = _WebSocket.query_params['name']

         # only proceed if templateName is defined.
         if _templateName:
            # send json response to client.
            await _WebSocket.send_json({ 'templateReply': 'RecivedData' }, mode= 'binary')

       # close socket connection.
       await _WebSocket.close()

     # return none. as application is
     # run on socket.
     return None

   # SERVER RUN
   if __name__ == '__main__':
     # run server.
     uvicorn.run(App, host= _host, port = _port)
   ```
2. Node.js

   ```
   // if _user information found than do login verification. else do
   // refresh @Cr for user information.
   // if _BroadCast contains data set.
   let _io = IO.connect('http://localhost:8000', {
     'path': '/chat',
     'transports': ['websocket'],
     'query': {
       'name': 'monk',
       'POST': 'dotsinspace@gmail.com'
     }
   })

   _io.on('connection', async () => {
      console.log('connected to user....') // log: nothing
   })
   _io.on('reconnecting', (__connection) => {
      console.log(__connection) // log: 2, 3 etc....
   })
   ```
3. Result
   [Socket Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R1jy.png)

Comment: Node.js usually used as a server, not a client. Are you using this? https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js client for a socket.io server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703513/node-js-client-for-a-socket-io-server)

Comment: Why not a client-side ? and yes i am using same link u provided :0

Comment: Anyway - check this sample answer, it can help you to write the client https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427353/3107689

Comment: Why not a client-side ? :(

Comment: No reason at all, I just say 'usually'. Anyway you need a way to test the server and the client with a tool you know already work. It will be much easier to debug.